# KnockoutJS: How to get default item from select option and pass as argument to another function when page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a select option which is populated via binding. Based on the selected or default value, the `Continent` is passed as argument to another function which populates a table with country information in relations to the continent selected. In a nutshell, the table is populated based on the continent, however this is also done when the page first loads:

Here is a [complete Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/9nd82f6e/1/):

*Additional info:*

[image]

I am attempting to load additional data for country detail when the page loads using the first record in the table. I need to pass the Country ID back to a `function` in the `view model`.

Illustration:

[image]

Currently, I am using a click event to population the additional data, like this:

```
<table id="country-list">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>CountryID</th>
        <th>Country Name</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Continent</th>
        <th>CountryAbbr</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind= "foreach: FilteredCountries">

      <!-- Return row data to CountryDetails and use the info to
           bind data based on row clicked-->

    <tr data-bind="click: $root.CountryDetails, clickBubble: false">
        <td data-bind="text: CountryId"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Country"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: City"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Continent"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: CountryAbbr"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

*Code:*

```
self.CountryDetails = function(country)
{
    var data = ko.computed(function() {

        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.CountryDetailData(), function(item) {
            return item.CountryId === country.CountryId;
        });
    });

    self.CountryId(data()[0].CountryId);
    self.Location(data()[0].Location);
    self.Coordinates(data()[0].Coordinates);
    self.Coastline(data()[0].Coastline);
    self.Climate(data()[0].Climate);
    self.Terrain(data()[0].Terrain);
}
```

[Complete example code in fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/9nd82f6e/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `CountryDetails` with the first country in `FilteredCountries` upon binding the model:

```
var vm = new ViewModel;
ko.applyBindings(vm);

vm.CountryDetails(vm.FilteredCountries()[0]);
```

You can also highlight the chosen row using the following:

```
// CSS
tbody tr.active { background-color: #ccc; }

// HTML
<tr data-bind="click: $root.CountryDetails, clickBubble: false, css: { active: $root.IsActiveRow(CountryId) }">

// JS
self.IsActiveRow = function (countryId) {
    return countryId == self.CountryId();
}
```

See updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9nd82f6e/4/)

Comment: This is so cool: Started using Knockout only few days ago and I have learned so much, especially from your responses. Thank you so much my friend.